# 10,000,000+ questions preemptive bug attack

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, 10m-questions-milestone

Having 8 digits or more questions asked breaks the layout and looks bad.

When Stack Overflow hits its 10th million question, it'll be an extraordinary event, likely celebrated with shenanigans, riots, and lots of crying with pure hysteria. If my uneducated guess calculations are correct, the 10th million question will be asked sometime in February of 2015. So please fix this bug before the end of the year, just in case!

[image]

Comment: I think we should wait 'till it breaks, just for the lulz.

Comment: nah we just need to keep purging question and remain forever under the 10 mil, much less effort ;)

Comment: @ratchetfreak that would be satisfactory

Comment: Just switch to hexadecimal.

Comment: And as a bonus we will end up with 9,999,999 *perfect* questions.

Comment: @Mike, hampers the user, only delays the problem... I like it ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Hampers the user? We are all enthusiastic or professional programmers here, says so in our manifest.

Comment: @Deduplicator, indeed it does. I saw you coming with your 2d92 rep and your 23 bronze badges.

Comment: The mere thought that the SE programmers wouldn't know how to deal with a 7 digit number is ridiculous.  They've tackled *way* bigger problems than that.

Comment: @HansPassant Such as ["viewed 1 times"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times).

Comment: You mean... it's not like an odometer? It's not just gonna flip over to all 0s? Damn! I was looking forward to that...

Comment: Stack Overflow in 3014: http://prntscr.com/4n9qxg

Comment: @Shashank So there will still be poor quality php questions?

Comment: not preemptive enough, we need to prepare for 100,000,000 questions

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: After deliberate cogitation, I've come to the conclusion that base-16 does not really do my towering reputation justice. Let's use octal, or better yet binary.

Comment: `If my uneducated guess calculations are correct, the 10th million question will be asked sometime in February of 2015.` lol +1

Comment: The solution to this problem is to delete questions more aggressively,  so we never reach that dangerous number!

Comment: 10,000,000th; and 25,000 of those will be worth having on the site! Yay for us.

Comment: @animuson you should now better than that... we're programmers. When it rolls over, it will be -9,999,998 questions.

Comment: I would much prefer they just expand `#container #content` to be wider than 980px... practically half of my 1920px resolution.

Comment: We will totally wait until the last minute, then panic and choose and ugly solution. People will revolt and we will invoke a designer to help us fix it.

Comment: y2k all over again..

Comment: Your prediction is about as true as my social life :) [See here](http://i.imgur.com/Vz0MHaG.png)

Comment: For the record, it happened today.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I've changed the size of the font on the display from `350%` to `315%` which, while a *tad* smaller, will allow an 8 digit number to display correctly. This will "future proof" us until the 100,000,000th question! It will be live in the next production build (meta: > `rev 2014.9.25.2605`, q&a: > `rev 2014.9.25.1892`).

Comment: The world is saved, once again.

Comment: Was it ever *truly* in danger? ;)

Comment: Look! The huge manatee!

Comment: a new design was implemented today. if this part that affects the questions asked remains, we are safe till the *tenth trillion (10,000,000,000,000)* question gets asked.

Answer (score 76):

I really like [Mike M.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m)'s idea to switch to hexadecimal numbers. I must say it looks really cool and it will confuse many people for sure. (That makes it even cooler). But the coolest thing about it is that you have to use a calculator if you are really interested in the number of asked questions. (Of course you can do it in your head but you have to be really passionate in mental arithmetic)

[image]

Just kidding. But I think that would be a cool easter egg. (Clicking on the number changes to hexadecimal) Or an April fool's trick. Or it could be display when the question count is in the range from 10,000,000 to 10,000,100...

Comment: Mathematicians are not particularly good at doing arithmetic in their heads.

Comment: -1 for erroneous statement, "confusing people makes it cooler".

Comment: Let's go binary. For the fun. For the win.

Comment: @leon Except that'd exacerbate the original problem. Make it a QR code instead.

Answer (score 17):

It's a bit silly, but

[image]

Answer (score 10):

It's a 1 line CSS fix.. As Robert Harvey said, "I think we should wait 'till it breaks, just for the lulz. ".  Or at 9.9 million shrink the font size and no lulz.

Comment: What fix are you suggesting? Reducing the font size? I'd rather see `10 mil. questions`

Comment: We could go the McDonald's route and say "Over 10 million questions served".

Comment: What is "lulz"? :]

Comment: @trejder .  A corruption of LOLs.  Meaning amusement at someone else's misfortune.  Often, but not always, used in a mean spirited fashion.

Comment: Bah. What's wrong with `10.123M`?

Comment: "10.0M", with a mouseover tooltip with the actual decimal number of questions in a regular, smaller font.

Comment: I think we're all in agreement that it should be a animated odometer that rolls up to the current question count, like those 1990s hit counters ... that or the McDonald's one. But my favorite so far is the bone crushing.