# Will Stack Overflow celebrate the 10M question milestone?

Tags: discussion, questions, 10m-questions-milestone

It seems like it would be a big(-ish) deal. 10,000,000 questions on Stack Overflow. Or is it only me?

Comment: Its only you! No one would really care much. But [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000000)'s the 10000000 post

Comment: Short answer, yeah - I plan on doing something. I'm not sure what yet, but it will probably involve plenty of tomfoolery and copious amounts of swag.

Comment: @Tim Post: I thought you weren't dealing with swag anymore :(

Comment: @BoltClock He clearly plans to *offer* the copious amounts of swag and then shove all the handling off onto us...

Comment: @BoltClock True, but Stack Overflow _is_ now my job (and only job), and we have folks on our ops team to help send it out. I'd hate to miss a chance for everyone to have some fun around a pretty awesome achievement for all of us.

Comment: @animuson Not _all_ of it, just almost all of it.

Comment: Surely a big deal. *gigantic* even ,   10 mil is a beautiful number. It's the private-jet league, the megacity, the multi-state lottery number. We need this to be **big**, like free-coffee-gift-cards for all big

Comment: @Coffee I'd be SO DOWN FOR THAT.

Comment: Historical records for those with 10k on MSE: [the original million-question contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/meta-raffle-when-will-stackoverflow-reach-one-million-questions) and [the second one with prizes from Stack Exchange (not that I'm bitter or anything)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54249/contest-to-predict-date-and-time-that-stackoverflow-will-eclipse-1-000-000-questi). Commemorated [on the blog](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/10/millionth-stack-overflow-question/).

Comment: Ha, completely forgot that [I won the second contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54249/contest-to-predict-date-and-time-that-stackoverflow-will-eclipse-1-000-000-questi)

Comment: You know, Joel has a *really* expensive gourmet coffee habit, as do I and a few others. A bag of beans from our personal selection isn't an unreasonable idea for some of the prizes.

Comment: @TimPost, first off, unicorns > rainbows. everyone knows that. second, you're surname is Post? and you work at SO? o_0.

Comment: @ericosg We almost named our second child 'meta post'.

Comment: @TimPost, dat swag. (i actually lol'ed)

Comment: I don't see how 0x00989680 questions is such a big deal. If we have 0x01000000 (or 16777216 for you decimal-based humans) then we should probably celebrate.

Comment: I would celebrate the primary key overflow.

Comment: The millionth post was easy to identify by its id. How do you do that for questions?

Comment: @Bergi https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/335841/the-10-million-dollar-question

Comment: @UniformsForSale I wish you would've linked to one of my posts ;) Look at all those upvotes

Answer (score 73, accepted):

#### Yes. But I'm not yet sure what we'll do.

It's been awhile since we just had a bit of fun here on meta and felt *great* about something awesome that just happened to this thing that every single one of us have worked so hard to build.

It will probably involve:

- Unicorns and rainbows
- Copious amounts of swag
- Silly, mindless and *extremely* fun contests where basically everyone that participates wins
- You not getting much work done that day

We won't do anything that leads to shenanigans on the main site, but we can have some fun here in the canteen. I'm also open to any ideas anyone has :)

Comment: You forgot to mention closing and downvoting the question.

Comment: @bjb568 - That is what worries me a little. Everyone anticipating this 10 millionth question and it's like "I have a desperate need for some code here thnx"

Comment: It *must* be somehow pre-planned. this is like the Superbowl . An army of Ivy League Computer Science majors must plan their questions beforetime, then unleash them all around question 9,999,950. Hopefully no troll gets in

Comment: The plan is mostly to intrigue Joel into doing something with COBOL _right_ around that time. Actually that's not the plan, but don't tell Joel that.

Comment: COBOL?  party-pooper..

Comment: hmmmm.... I've had a super weird assembly question in mind for a little while... wonder how well that would fly :P

Comment: How does one even figure out which is the 10th million question? Since total # of questions doesn't include deleted questions, the url id count is for both questions/answers, ie: posts. There is also caching to consider for regular users. It's possible that someone asks the 10th million question and two seconds later some old question is deleted, thus making the possibility for 2+ questions to be the 10th million question.

Comment: @bjb568 You got it. I [snagged number two million](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104199/134300) and it was immediately closed by metizens.

Comment: I'll level with you.  All I want is a hoodie.  Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Change the Stack Overflow logo to a rainbow for a day. Hey, look! No liberal, political agenda in sight - unless people *want* to read it in that.

Comment: You definitely want to have a question "at the ready" and auto-insert it as number 1E7. If you intend to celebrate it. It would have to come from a well respected member. Perhaps John Skeet could ask a question?

Comment: Mention "10 million" somewhere in its answer - and it should be part of the answer, not a 'mere mention'. This may even work if the question is a clear duplicate ("I vote to close because it is a duplicate of the following questions..." followed by 10 million links)

Comment: You know, if someone were to post "Predict the date of the 10th million question on SO" and ping me with a link, I'd endorse it with an offer of a swag box to the person that came the closest :) Not a bad place to start.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299058/predict-the-date-of-the-10th-million-questi0n-on-so

Comment: Expectation management: Said milestone question is _very_ likely to be unremarkable at **best**, please don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: @ericosg The celebration is going to take place _here_ on meta. We don't want to create a lot of noise about it on the main site, because that would mostly annoy people, and kinda kill the fun.

Comment: @Jongware: hah, you beat me to it! As soon as Tim suggested we're going to have rainbows, I thought _yay, let's have a logo change, there's bound to be a spare rainbow logo knocking around_ `:-)`.

Comment: But what if the 10,000,000th question is a low-quality, off-topic, or otherwise unfit question? WHAT IF ITS SPAM? Can the first 5 to close it get a swag bag?

Comment: Please offer stackoverflow t-shirts for sale again.

Comment: @TimPost: I am participating in the new main page design test. There does not seem to be the total question count anymore... Will it come back?

Comment: @juergend Just use search, `is:question` and you'll see the familiar tally again.

Comment: But no hats? :(

Comment: This genius suggestion found big acceptance: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271436/10-000-000-questions-preemptive-bug-attack/271490#271490

Comment: [10 000 000 question is here!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302884/1768232)

Comment: btw, i love the logo change. swaggy.

Answer (score 5):

It would be a big deal -- if computers used base ten. Why not wait until 1000000000000000000000000 to get excited?

Comment: Don't forget that some questions ask multiple things. That makes us too lazy to even consider the math, and now is more fun than later.

Comment: Actually, I'd rather only wait for 101010101010101010101010.Or maybe just until 100110011001100110011001.

Answer (score 1):

You kidding?

Celebrate 9M duplicated, low quality lazy questions with quick, dirty and stupid answers?

Would you celebrate 10Mth ton of garbage on a scrapheap?

Comment: Do you mean there are 1M useful well-researched questions with excellent insightful answers? You are such an optimist! :)

Comment: You're the living, breathing demotivational poster for SO. [This](http://i.imgur.com/w3LHUoI.jpg) seems appropriate :)

Comment: @CarrieKendall, Cmon, give the guy a break... and Are you sure you know whose photo that is?

Answer (score -2):

What strikes me as odd is the focus on quantity rather than quality. Surely if we need a stat, net upvotes would be better than a *meaningless* raw question count.

It's [getting](http://google.com/search?q=V) [subtle](http://google.com/search?q=C), but is it still quality first then quantity, or has it now been more about *[reach](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290491/632951)*?