# Don't answer - just vtc

Tags: discussion, answers, vote-to-close

Is there any issue with answering a bad question? I'm a regular user of several SE sites, most of which do not worry too heavily about regulating answers on questions that should be closed.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397654/newline-in-constant-for-inserting-in-the-database) was posted, and the issue was quite obvious. It could be put down to a typographical error. Someone pointed that out in the comments, and I then answered, explaining the point further.

I was later told that I should not have answered at all, and it seems as though my answering should be frowned upon.

Should I avoid answering bad questions altogether?

Comment: Yes, you should most definitely avoid answering bad questions. Then these questions can either be made into good questions through editing , or in the case of a simple typographical error, it will be deleted after 9 days if it has no answers with upvotes. If you post an answer and it gets upvoted, that question will live forever on Stack Overflow where it will be of use to no one

Comment: Downvote, Vote to close, or both. There are too many awful questions appearing on [so] and the friendly, try-to-help approach (or the 'build rep however I can' approach) is encouraging more and more, lazier and lazier questions. The quicker these are shut down the less janitorial work there is to do, and we can concentrate on answering something that might be more generally useful.

Comment: Worth remembering: Stack Overflow typically gets more questions in an hour than some sites will get in a week (or close to it). This community relies far more on the automated cleanup processes because it simply has to while sites like Arqade and ELL have enough 10k users to delete the closed crap manually.

Comment: Answering off topic questions will often gain you downvotes. Don't bother.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Should I avoid answering bad questions altogether?

In my opinion, yes. (Since it was my response to Ben that prompted this Meta question in the first place, I guess that's readily apparent :) ).

Bad questions are by definition bad for the site. Answering bad questions runs the risk of a bad question failing to be deleted through the normal automated processes. It also runs the risk of encouraging a person who posted a bad question to do it again, rather than try harder next time to avoid posting a bad question, adding to the load of bad questions (which on Stack Overflow is considerable…YMMV on other Stack Exchange sites).

That said, there has been a fair amount of debate on this topic already in previous Meta questions, and opinions are divided. Of particular note is that some people disagree with the premise that a person who posts a bad question can be taught to not post bad questions.

On the flip side, there are those who argue that one should not provide *any* useful information to people who post bad questions, even in the comments. I obviously disagree with that position as well (since I provided the typographical correction needed in the question at hand).

Please see these related questions (I'm sure there are others, but these are the ones I found right off the bat):

[How to decide which questions I should not answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254549/3538012)
[Stance on answering “bad” questions [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281793/3538012)
[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/3538012)
[Should downvotes be used to punish people who answer bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255853/3538012)

Comment: On the other hand... the more useless questions are preserved, the sooner we get to [celebrate 10M questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299003/will-stack-overflow-celebrate-the-10m-question-milestone)!

Comment: Answering bad questions in the comments is just as bad as posting an answer to the same question in that it doesn't teach the user to post good questions, and they will come back and post the same way again, it does have one leg-up on actually posting an answer which is that it doesn't interfere with the roomba procedures.

Comment: @TinyGiant: that is one opinion, yes. But it fails to take into account that a vote-to-close should provide sufficient feedback to the OP to understand _why_ their question is being closed. Simply pointing out the typographical error that justifies the close reason is IMHO perfectly fine (and indeed, necessary).

Comment: @TinyGiant Answering bad questions in the comments is worse than posting a bad answer, because answers should never go in the comments, bad or otherwise. Now, the situation that PeterDuniho pointed out is acceptable, because instead of answering their question, you're giving an explanation as to why their question is being closed (Which will help the asker in the future should they return to ask a question know whats acceptable).

Comment: On the other hand, I see far too often on typographical questions people put the 3 or 4 word answer in the comments, then flag to close, so the asker sees the answer, leaves, and never realizes that some hour or two later their question was closed. That should be avoided because it allows the asker to think that the bad behavior is acceptable.

Comment: @DavyM I'm not sure I agree.

Comment: @TinyGiant What part do you not agree with? As for the answering in the comments being worse, any time you hit the `Add Comment` button, you are met with a notice that says explicitly `Avoid answering questions in the comments.` Comments are simply not the place for answers. Whenever a person posts an answer, it should be able to be voted on as good or bad; that's why we have a voting system. If someone slides their answer into a comment, it can no longer be downvoted for being a bad answer. Answering in the comments completely disregards the purpose of the question/answer voting system.

Comment: @DavyM I dont agree with a blanket statement that no one should ever post something that may qualify as an answer in a comment. Of course answering questions in the comments should be _avoided_, but it should _not_ be outlawed. There are many times where I may have a potential solution but I'm unsure if it will work for the OP, so I'll post a comment and if the OP says that it will work then I'll post an answer, along with a whole host of other situations where leaving a possible solution in the comments would be appropriate. I think your black-and-white view of this is detrimental.

Comment: Hell, sometimes I just don't feel like taking the time to flesh out my solution into a full fledged answer, so I post it in a comment. If someone else wants to come along to expand my comment into a proper answer, that is absolutely fine. Anyway, I'm sure @Peter is tired of the notifications here so if you would like to continue discussing this we should take it to chat.