# 10,000,000th question is here!

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

Remember one month ago we talked about the 10M question?

[Will Stack Overflow celebrate the 10M question milestone?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299003/will-stack-overflow-celebrate-the-10m-question-milestone)

IT'S HERE!!!

[image]

> Short answer, yeah - I plan on doing something. I'm not sure what yet, but it will probably involve plenty of tomfoolery and copious amounts of swag

> It will probably involve:
>
> - Unicorns and rainbows
> - Copious amounts of swag
> - Silly, mindless and extremely fun contests where basically everyone that participates wins
> - You not getting much work done that day

So @TimPost can we have our swag now? And fun and unicorns?

Comment: ... but which question is the 10,000,000 one?

Comment: yippee doo... wow... how excitin... zzzzz

Comment: @rene dunno, couldn't find it. Just say 10M + 2 so posted it

Comment: @rene http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114584/got-node-gyp-rebuild-status-1-issue-when-installed-nodebb

Comment: @Tim 32,114,584

Comment: @Tim - You weren't in incognito mode so that is filtered by your preferences. I wasn't either and saw a different one. (But having said that the question you linked isn't the third one on your screenshot anyway?)

Comment: I was witnessing the 10M milestone. Is there anyway that we can really extract the 10M th question ?

Comment: @JudeNiroshan Very difficult. The past keeps getting rewritten.

Comment: For all we know, its spam and already deleted

Comment: Perhaps just relax the criteria a little; the question *counter* has hit 10mil, who cares about the actual truth? :)

Comment: @MartinSmith I think 2 were deleted in that time - I don't know if the count included it.

Comment: @tchrist That number includes answers.

Comment: According to [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/abOfd.png) from [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299058/lets-predict-the-date-of-the-ten-millionth-question-on-stack-overflow/299066#comment235895_299066) it was [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32114574/1114)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/10m <- why are there 16M solutions for 10M questions?

Comment: @jp-jee because questions can have multiple answers?

Comment: answer != solution (which I would expect to be an accepted answer, of which there is none or one for each question).

Comment: @jp-jee A question can have multiple *solutions*. Accepting an answer doesn't mean it was the only valid answer or even that it is the *best* answer. It's just the answer the OP decided to accept.

Comment: @jp-jee: because there are [16 million answers with score 0 or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+score%3A0..).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you may :) [The first of these events was just posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey). There will be 2 or 3 per week for the next two weeks, anyone that wants in on the fun will have ample opportunity to join.

We'll also be contacting the author of the closest guess on the related thread.

NOW GO GET SOME.