# What was the 10 millionth question?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

Congrats to Stack Overflow on 10 million questions! Out of curiosity, what was the 10 millionth question?

Comment: @Qix it was definitely not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000000/

Comment: According to [Jonny 5's screenshot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299058/lets-predict-the-date-of-the-ten-millionth-question-on-stack-overflow#comment235895_299066), it would be [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32114574/1048572). However, I guess since older questions are constantly deleted, it's more a floating range…

Comment: [In that screenshot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302884/1048572) there's some other candidate

Comment: Which ever question turns out to be the 10 millionth, please don't spam a bunch of "WOW CONGRATZ" comments on it :|

Comment: @meagar this is already happening on the first question Bergi linked :P I don't think you'll be able to stop those to pop up... no matter how off-topic these comments are :(

Comment: @Patrice and the (non-so-aptly) named "historical lock" would also likely be inappropriate.

Comment: @Bergi Not necessarily, if they had any _ignored tags_ preventing some questions from showing up.

Comment: I tried the query `SELECT * FROM Posts LIMIT 1 OFFSET 10000000` on [SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), but it didn't work :(

Comment: @Tim I think you mean [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353256), but (I believe) this doesn't take deleted posts into account.

Comment: @Tim: [data.SE does not include deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157462/137096). There are [less than 10M questions according to data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353263/number-of-questions). Here's [a millionth question](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353261/find-n-th-question?n=1000000)

Comment: "I tried teh codez but it didn't working.  I kept getting the error.   Pls help mee"

Comment: @Dukeling: there is off-by-one error. [Use this instead](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353261/find-n-th-question)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian it's not giving any results.

Comment: @nginx: Pass `n` (<1e10) explicitly. There is no `n=10000000` question yet. [Read the previous comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302933/what-was-the-10-millionth-question?noredirect=1#comment236693_302933)

Comment: Oh, and of course the data in Data SE is a bit behind - [it gets synced every Monday](http://data.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: I want to know what was the **9999999th** question.

Comment: @topher That's linked to the 10 millionth comment not question

Comment: @Lankymart: It happens that [id1 < id2 does *not* imply that question1 is older than quesiton2](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353375/check-whether-id1-id2-implies-question1-is-older-than-question2). I've assumed incorrectly. Therefore [the query for 1M question returns only an approximate result](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353261/find-n-th-question?n=1000000) that is probably ok because even old questions can be deleted and therefore the result is not precise anyway.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Could you not just use `ORDER BY CreationDate ASC` instead?

Comment: @Lankymart: I can. I've updated the query. It is one more example why you should avoid premature optimization.

Comment: I had an attempt at a method using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353373/find-n-th-question?n=10000000)

Comment: Great way to earn the "Famous Question" badge... Drop a link here (like the one @Bergi did) and everyone will want to see (including me).

Comment: @Lankymart: [both queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353373/find-n-th-question?n=1000000) return [the same result](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353261/find-n-th-question?n=1000000) for `n=1e6`.  I'm not very familiar with T-SQL. Should there be a difference?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Tbh no, `OFFSET` is newer and maybe slightly more efficient but don't quote me.

Comment: +1, this.my_friend, was your 100th upvote and my 10th comment ^_^

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are many 10-millionth questions - at different times. We only are counting non-deleted questions, and questions are constantly getting deleted ([at notable rates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303027/1048572)). So even when [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353037/10-millionth-questions) will show some results as soon as the data dump will have been updated, it will only show the results of the day. There's a sliding window - post your question right now and it will likely be the 10 millionth question on SO at some time, when enough of the ones preceding it have been deleted.

So which was the first ten millionth question, the first to throw the counter above the 7-(decimal)-digit mark? We likely will never know, unless some SO employee will run an SQL query on the live data and takes deletion history into account.
But I don't think that's necessary. Neither will the author [get a new car](https://xkcd.com/570/), nor is that particular question actually significant:

## Every single question counts towards the number.

The [first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4/1048572) does as much as the last. The ten millionth question sits atop the shoulders of a giant mountain - even if that mountain is melting. **All of you guys have done an [amazing job](https://stackoverflow.com/10m)!**

Comment: But which was the **first** 10-millionth question?

Comment: I'd like to believe there was some automated counter that turned on the 10m page, logo and toast, and if so it would be interesting to know which one caused the activation. But as you rightfully pointed out, it wouldn't be 10M without the other 10M-1.

Comment: @topher It wasn't automated. We didn't put up the banner until we were about 5,000 over the 10M mark.

Comment: Wouldn't it be awkward if we went back under 10M?

Comment: @PyRulez: Not gonna happen, unless the community would decide to nuke half of the page. While we may loose about 600 old and recent questions per day, there are also about 6000 new questions asked per day.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [data.SE query for n-th question](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353261/find-n-th-question) (no result until the next update), here's [/10m question according to SO API](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?page=10000000&pagesize=1&order=asc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow) (it changes from request to request). I don't know whether it includes locked questions [that it shouldn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302852/4279).

Comment: It does include historical locks; you can test this by replacing 10000000 with the current question count from the site incremented by 300.