# Let's predict the date of the ten millionth question on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, status-completed, 10m-questions-milestone

> [You know, if someone were to post "Predict the date of the 10th million question on SO" and ping me with a link, I'd endorse it with an offer of a swag box to the person that came the closest :)](/posts/comments/219428)

So, when will it happen?

**Rules:** The question must *last* (not be deleted) during the entire day that you predict (UTC).

**Note:** The new navigation gives the wrong number of results on the home page because of [this <strike>bug</strike> feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260026/as-the-newest-questions-located-on-the-main-page-with-the-new-nav-all-the-low-s). If you're going to check the current number of questions using the homepage and have opted in to use the new navigation, go incognito.

Guesses so far:

```
+------------+----------------------------------+
| 2015-07-25 |                                  |
| 2015-07-26 |                                  |
| 2015-07-27 | PM 77-1                          |
| 2015-07-28 | Chris Baker                      |
| 2015-07-29 | Bright                           |
| 2015-07-30 | bjb568                           |
| 2015-07-31 | Joe W                            |
| 2015-08-01 | Andy                             |
| 2015-08-02 | Alexander O'Mara                 |
| 2015-08-03 | Jay Bosamiya                     |
| 2015-08-04 | Caleb                            |
| 2015-08-05 | Dronehinge                       |
| 2015-08-06 | Martijn Pieters♦                 |
| 2015-08-07 | DizzyCode                        |
| 2015-08-08 | towc                             |
| 2015-08-09 | Jon Clements♦                    |
| 2015-08-10 | Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå             |
| 2015-08-11 | michaelpri                       |
| 2015-08-12 | TZHX                             |
| 2015-08-13 | Lucas Trzesniewski               |
| 2015-08-14 | Makoto                           |
| 2015-08-15 | Martin Smith                     |
| 2015-08-16 | Dónal                            |
| 2015-08-17 | George Duckett                   |
| 2015-08-18 | Rizier123                        |
| 2015-08-19 | Dom                              |
| 2015-08-20 | Jeremy Banks♦                    |
| 2015-08-21 | Firedrake969                     |
| 2015-08-22 | Ethan Bierlein                   |
| 2015-08-23 | HugoRune                         |
| 2015-08-24 | Cheezey                          |
| 2015-08-25 | Dendromaniac                     |
| 2015-08-26 | Awal Garg                        |
| 2015-08-27 | ericosg                          |
| 2015-08-28 | Tanner                           |
| 2015-08-29 | ComFreek                         |
| 2015-08-30 | Cool Guy                         |
| 2015-08-31 | tox123                           |
| 2015-09-01 | Travis J                         |
| 2015-09-02 | NathanOliver                     |
| 2015-09-03 | Joe                              |
| 2015-09-04 | Dustiny                          |
| 2015-09-05 | OhBeWise                         |
| 2015-09-06 | leoraelkins                      |
| 2015-09-07 | Marko                            |
| 2015-09-08 | ninjalj                          |
| 2015-09-09 | DeadChex                         |
| 2015-09-10 | Jashaszun                        |
| 2015-09-11 | Ander Biguri                     |
| 2015-09-12 | Origence                         |
| 2015-09-13 | War10ck                          |
| 2015-09-14 |                                  |
| 2015-09-15 | Félix Gagnon-Grenier             |
|            |                                  |
| 2015-09-18 | Emrakul                          |
|            |                                  |
| 2015-10-02 | Frédéric Hamidi                  |
| 2015-10-03 | hochy                            |
|            |                                  |
| 2015-10-07 | onebree                          |
|            |                                  |
| 2015-10-11 | The Walking Dead season 6 starts |
| 2015-10-12 | Slapout                          |
|            |                                  |
| 2015-10-19 | ruffp                            |
| 2015-10-20 |                                  |
| 2015-10-21 | Will                             |
| 2015-10-22 |                                  |
| 2015-10-23 | Jamal                            |
| 2015-10-24 | sshow                            |
| 2015-10-25 |                                  |
| 2015-10-26 | shellbye                         |
|            |                                  |
| 2015-10-31 | Grant Winney                     |
| 2015-11-01 |                                  |
| 2015-11-02 | BeatAlex                         |
|            |                                  |
| 2015-11-05 | Quill                            |
| 2015-11-06 | ᔕᖺᘎᕊ                            |
|            |                                  |
| 2015-12-14 | ❄ HATS! ❄ (Winter Bash)          |
+------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: A 'box of swag' will be shipped to the person with the closest guess.

Comment: Are deleted questions included?

Comment: @TZHX No, because then we are way past 10M already: SO has about 12-13M questions. Which, by the way, opens the possibility to reach this milestone *more than once*.

Comment: @TZHX It has to remain on the site for at least the duration of the day that you predict. (UTC)

Comment: The question can't be deleted, but does it have to remain open?

Comment: @Makoto If we exclude closed questions, the count is quite different: 9.3M as of now. Also, the concept of "the 10,000,000th question" is ill defined, because older questions keep winking in and out of existence all the time. It's better to talk about having 10,000,000 questions, rather than "the 10,000,000th question".

Comment: I think that it's going to have to be "guess the date and time" not just "date" as that limits the number of participants quite severely?

Comment: Even though this *is* meta, I'm surprised to see prediction being downvoted. It's not going to help yours win instead. :P

Comment: @MartinSmith Apologies, I merely added the quote formatting. I may have caused a conflict.

Comment: Ah, what the... Anyone, *write a stack snippet insead of editing it*....

Comment: The rule about the question not being deleted only seems relevant if the question is posted right before midnight, and the next question is after midnight.

Comment: It is probably going to be in 6-8 weeks..

Comment: It seems a bit late to change the rules now, but wouldn't it make more sense to guess a date and time? Thaybway two people could guess the same day, so it is not so much a first come first serve thing

Comment: @HugoRune assume that there are finite yet plenty of swag boxes available.

Comment: Longest edited question.Should get a badge.

Comment: we need to have a closing date! then again, all possible dates could be closed by then. hmm. i guess its ok as is.

Comment: Why are so many responses down voted? I don't see a reason to down vote something here, as long as they provide a date.

Comment: Regardless of whomever asks the millionth question, i think we can all agree with will be answered by [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

Comment: @onebree : my guess is someone who hopes to get the swag if his/her question gets the most votes.

Comment: How are duplicate guesses handled? I am not able to edit the question so added an answer with my guess and later the question was edited and someone else put in a claim for the date I guessed.

Comment: This should be migrated to PCG. They calculate things like that in 9 bytes.

Comment: Can I get the data on total questions by month over the last 6 years?

Comment: @Chris Baker - [Joe got there first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299178/73226)

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for letting me know -- you could have just edited it out and I'd not have noticed, so really, thanks for being considerate. TBH, I didn't dig through the answers, I figured anyone who was guessing would have edited themselves in, I was NOT considerate and didn't factor for those without the rep to edit. I entered a more optimistic guess, not because I'm optimistic, but because my guess is gone and I think the new one is open :)

Comment: @ChrisBaker - Yes the SO question and answer format isn't really designed for this!

Comment: @GrantWinney Hah!  Possibly.  Was looking to graph it out.  :)

Comment: @GrantWinney Oh cool!  I didn't even know that was a thing.

Comment: At the time of this writing, we have 2,495,428 deleted questions. Please hold while I make that into a nice round number.

Comment: Can someone edit this, such that it is `onebree / Hunter Stevens`? I do not have such privilege.

Comment: the first deaths are already coming in.

Comment: Someone with edit privilege (and initiative) should (*regularly*?) update the post with the current question count.

Comment: @TimPost Would this be the same 'box 'o swag' that the 100K members get?

Comment: @j08691 A slightly different box-o-swag. This one will be full of calendars.

Comment: @TimPost - The 10M mark is supposed to be checked from incognito mode in chrome for the official count right? When logged in the number is a little different is why I asked.

Comment: No edits here? :)

Comment: I've removed the migration history from this question (it was originally posted on Stack Overflow) to prevent it from being automatically deleted as a "rejected migration" when the other questions from the ten million milestone are preserved.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### August 20th, 2015

is my prediction based on the question asking rate over the last month, according to the value listed on `/questions` in the Internet Archive.

Comment: Hacking SO and changing the question count on that day is not allowed, not even for mods :)

Comment: Looking good for this prediction based on increase from last week.

Comment: Looks like you will be the winner? Congrats!?!1

Comment: @rizier https://twitter.com/stackstatus/status/634035689668087808 It's too close for my liking. ;)

Comment: @JeremyBanks With 7.8k questions per day and right now with a count of: 9'997k questions. It's pretty save that you got this one. (Now you can award yourself the hacker badge again :)

Comment: @Rizier123 there's still 3 hours to go until midnight UTC and only 1,231 questions needed. Dom might sneak it!

Comment: 875 left with a little over 2 hours to go.  It will be me or you (most likely you).

Comment: Hmm, I see the number of questions has had a few drops lately where the number has gone down after I refresh the page. Hope no frenetic moderator activity by any interested parties!

Comment: @JeremyBanks Well now it's definitive, you won :)

Comment: Now 1967 to go which is up 400+ from a few minutes ago

Comment: The counter is at ☆ *9,999,990*  it's happening  :S

Comment: 10,000,002 - now.

Comment: Did [this screenshot](http://snag.gy/g2qyU.jpg). Well, congrats SO

Comment: It would be a diamond mod to win the prize.  Seriously though, congrats.

Comment: Congrats to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @JeremyBanks and to you!

Comment: @Jonny5 I like how the question right on top is a C++ one saying the regex doesn't match with a -1 vote, that is *so SO*. :P

Comment: YOU WIN :) I'll be in touch.

Comment: @Jonny5: So [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32114574/1048572) is ten-millionth question?

Comment: are you a wizard?

Comment: @Bergi I was logged in when I did the screenshot, sorted newest. No idea :]

Comment: @JeremyBanks Could you explain further how you can up with today's date? My guess (onebree) was for October.

Comment: SHENANIGANS!  ***SHENANIGANS!***

Comment: ***I CANNOT EVEN...!***

Comment: Yer a wizard, Jerry.

Answer (score 46):

I printed off a monthly calendar for July and August and stuck 'em to the dart board. After my 15th attempt at actually hitting anything with my eyes closed, my highly technical system says it's going to be **August 9th**.

Comment: If you have always asked yourself how teachers make the grades, that's how ^^.

Comment: Well, everyone know that, that is how appraisals are done :D

Comment: A real coder would have thrown a fistful of darts and averaged them, after asking on SO how to do that in COBOL

Comment: @Machavity and I suppose bring a ninja puppy I should have used shurikens instead...

Comment: I tried this method and chose **my coworker's leg**.

Comment: @Machavity nah, a real coder would have recorded the static radio frequencies of five satellites, mixed their signals, and rounded them to min and max amplitudes to generate a graph of binary data to use as the source code of a robot, which then does what you describe.

Comment: If this turns out to be true, I know what I'll be posting that day...

Comment: @BoltClock if this turns out to be true - I'm using this technique to pick the winning lottery numbers :)

Answer (score 39):

## c# - OMG! null reference exception why? [duplicate]

> This question already has an answer here:
> [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142) *33 answers*

i get error, why? Here's code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var me = new Me();
    You.Complete<Me> girlfriend = null;

    while (!me.Stupid)
    {
        girlfriend.Ignore();
    }

}

class Me { public bool Stupid { get { return false; } } }
class You { public class Complete<T> { public void Ignore() { } } }
```

Plz help me!!!!! xoxo

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [unicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unicorn)

<sub>[share](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299080/3459110)  [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/299080/edit)  [close](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299058/predict-the-date-of-the-10th-million-question-on-so)  [flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299058/predict-the-date-of-the-10th-million-question-on-so)</sub>                      asked Aug 10, 2015 at 13:13
                              ||||||||   [user93823734344](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299058/predict-the-date-of-the-10th-million-question-on-so)
                              ||||||||   1

Comment: If you get that posted as the 10mio. question, then you can say: omg

Comment: This one wouldn't last the whole day for sure :-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Surely we could make an exception for this one, If it was actually the 10 Millionth Q. I mean that just deserves so much :3

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this behavior. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

Comment: Let's make this a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have close votes unlocked yet, this is a scam

Answer (score 25):

That is easy.

The 10,000,000 question will be asked on [6 - 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) August 2015

Comment: If  my answer makes a couple of us smile, I'm more than happy. No swag for me then.

Answer (score 19):

## October 23, 2015 at 06:02 UTC

And it'll be tagged as: [chemistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) [moles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moles) [atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atom) [flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask) [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium)

Comment: Why do you think it will be asked on my 40th birthday?

Comment: @psubsee2003: Avogadro, is that you?

Comment: Is this expanding to the entire SE network? Or is this just a meme...

Answer (score 19):

### 2015-08-23

But it's so simple. All I have to do is divine from what I know of the other posters: Are they the sort of persons who guesses early or guesses late?

Now, a clever man would do the math, and guess the most likely date based on that. But since that guess is already taken, I cannot possibly choose the middle of August.

Usually these things happen faster than expected, so I should guess the latest free date before the middle of august. But most other answerers will have had the same thought, so I cannot possibly chose anything before the middle of august.

The obvious choice would then be...

What in the world can that be ...?

Well, I- I could have sworn I saw something. No matter. First, let's guess: 2015-08-23

Comment: Very good. I made a similar calculation and also got a date that already has been taken. Now, I cannot tell you what it was, but I *can* tell you I got the right one!

Comment: Truly, you have a dizzying intellect.  ;)

Comment: Never go against a Sicilian when rep is on the line!

Comment: That was close enough, should be awarded with a mini box of swagness.

Answer (score 15):

At the time of this post, there were 9,754,349 questions (245,651) away from 10,000,000 and according to the [SE site stats](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#traffic), SO has been getting 7,956 questions per day. It is 17:05 UTC, approximately 71% percent through the day, which means that there have been about 5,649 questions asked today. That means there are still 2,307 questions left to be asked today, so there will be 9,756,633 questions at the beginning of Sunday, July 12, 2015. That means there will be 247,958 questions till 10,000,000. So now we divide that by 7,956 and we get roughly 31 days until we reach 10,000,000. This means that SO's 10 millionth question will be on

### Tuesday, August 11th, 2015 at 4:04 UTC

---

<sup>Note: please feel free to correct me if I have made any incorrect calculations :)</sup>

Comment: I made an error in my calculations. I think either August 11th or 12th is when it will happen.

Comment: I was going to do exactly this very early this morning.... but then my daughter wanted to play a game.  So I didn't get the time to do the math.  Fortunately kids are worth the loss of any kind of cool swag.

Comment: Is that 7,956 questions per day from inception or recently? You might need to se calculus to factor in the increasing number of questions as the site becomes more popular rather than assuming a flat average.

Comment: @Caltor I believe that 7,956 was the average number of questions per day for the past one/two weeks before I posted this. My math was wrong anyway :(

Answer (score 10):

## 2015-08-19

At 7.9k questions per day it's the most likely that's open.

Comment: This answer could likely be an off-by-one error. :( We will see soon! The pressure is so intense!

Comment: @CRABOLO I know it's getting very close :). If by the end of the day it's over 991k I'll most likely get it as weekdays seem to have an average of about 9k.

Answer (score 8):

My personal bet would be on:

## Friday, October 2nd, 16:45:58 UTC

That's trying to account for:

- The relative decrease in traffic during July and August,
- The natural decay of questions, manually or automatically initiated (the roomba does not take holidays),
- The crapstorm that will hit us in September, with a fresh batch of developers-in-learning asking us how to print an integer in C (hopefully those questions should be deleted as they arrive, although the duplicate effect may soften this),
- Possibly, the other kind of crapstorm that will hit Europe real soon now (and then most of us living there will be rushing to the bank to try and withdraw our now-worthless assets instead of posting on SO).

I took these factors, added four, multiplied by two (my usual time-to-milestone estimation algorithm), and got somewhere around the beginning of October, which matches the fifth anniversary of my joining the site quite well. So I chose that and left the rest to karma.

Answer (score 7):

I choose:

### August 16th, 2015

Answer (score 6):

I'll say **August 21st** based on the statistics, accounting for a little rounding up on the questions/day.
Also, the earlier dates were taken :(

Comment: Your answer probably has off-by-one error :( There is a chance though! Have hope and swag! Pressure is mounting.

Comment: Hoping for about 3.3k questions a day, I guess :(

Comment: This is looking like it will be pretty close.

Comment: Not my day, I think...

Comment: Based on the current rate _(negative 2 questions per minute)_ it's a possibility. But once the delete votes are used up, it looks like you're off by one.

Comment: Noooooo!  At least I was close :)

Answer (score 5):

## 2015-08-03

The almighty Google, says that [the answer to life, the universe, and everything](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=the%20answer%20to%20life%20the%20universe%20and%20everything) is 42. Considering that we are not fortunate enough to understand what the 42 really means, we choose to flip it around to get a 24. Coincidentally, `8*3 == 24`.

Comment: September 24 = Illuminati Confirmed! Lol

Answer (score 5):

### October <sub>the <sub>2nd <sub><sub>as <sub>nobody <sub>else <sub>has <sub>said <sub>it, <sub>although <sub>it's <sub>my <sub>birthday <sub>on <sub>the <sub>6th <sub>of <sub>August <sub>but <sub>Martijn <sub>got <sub>[there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299063/1317805) <sub>first!</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

#Free #Swag

Comment: I already said july 30.

Comment: @bjb568 psh. Changed. :(

Comment: [Already taken by Frédéric Hamidi](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299058/lets-predict-the-date-of-the-ten-millionth-question-on-stack-overflow/299144#299144)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that 1 in 10 new questions are deleted every day, I say that the day that the 10 millionth question is created will be:

## Friday, 14 August 2015

Answer (score 3):

I'm going for

### 21:42 UTC, August 7, 2015

Comment: Stack Exchange generally uses UTC, and the time you've specified would be on August 8th UTC. But someone else claimed that date a couple of minutes after you. Is it alright if  August 7th UTC is used as your prediction, to resolve the conflict?

Comment: Haha sure. It's just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

2015 / 8 = 251.875

**2015-8-25 18:75** (not possible)

---

The 75 overflows into another hour so:

**2015-8-25 19:15**

Answer (score 3):

Put me down for early rather than late. That way if the swag gods do show me favor I have a chance of seeing it before summer is over. My mail takes a while. **2015-08-04**.

Answer (score 3):

## July 27th between 9 AM and 6 PM EDT

For two very good reasons:

1. It seems to be still available
2. Because

Comment: 3. Underdog (by far)

Answer (score 3):

## August 27, 2015

I actually wanted 28th since it's a number I always chose, even though I hate it. Rather don't ask.

So I copy pasted the first available gap. Well, the list is pretty long at the moment, I guess I came in late.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I like the call the "Math.random" factor, I have discovered an algorithm written entirely in javascript for finding out the exact date. Now I have been working on this for a while, and believe I successfully created a model to figure it out:

```
var tenMillionQuestionAlgorithm = function(){
    return round(Math.random()) + " Days Before the Ten Millionth SO Question"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll go for

### 15 August 2015

as we need another 245,672 questions (and that looks like about 35 days worth).

[image]

---

Though this is now looking <strike>highly unlikely</strike> impossible and I expect it will be 5 days later (following question numbers all taken late afternoon UTC on successive Saturdays).

```
+-----------+-----------------------+------------------+
|   Date    | Approx # of Questions | Weekly           |
|           | till target           | Reduction        |
+-----------+-----------------------+------------------+
| 11-Jul-15 | 246,000               |                  |
| 18-Jul-15 | 203,000               | 43,000           |
| 25-Jul-15 | 159,000               | 44,000           |
| 01-Aug-15 | 116,000               | 43,000           |
| 08-Aug-15 |  74,000               | 42,000           |    
| 15-Aug-15 |  32,000               | 42,000           |  
| 22-Aug-15 |  -8,000               | 40,000           |  
+-----------+-----------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Though revisisting this a week later we still need 203K questions so if that rate stays consistent it won't happen until 5 or 6 days later than my initial guess.

Comment: And another week later we need 159K questions so the rate is consistent at 44k a week.

Comment: As of now, I believe that this will be the date of the 10 millionth question

Comment: @michaelpri I don't. We are still 74,000 away and it seems quite consistent that 43,000 questions a week are asked. My guess is exactly one week from today. I think Jeremy Banks's guess is the most likely. 5 days after mine.

Answer (score 1):

August 12th, cos that be my birthday.

I don't think question asking is going to go up substantially -- isn't summer generally a bit quieter?

Comment: I've heard that winter is slower and that's why they have Winterbash to increase activity during that time.

Comment: @Dronehinge I thought Winterbash was so that everyone could have hats to keep their heads warm in the winter?

Answer (score 1):

I [already made a prediction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271436/10-000-000-questions-preemptive-bug-attack) so I think I'm officially out of the running now.

But just for fun I'll guess again :p

## **August 5th, 2015**

Comment: Oh wow, February 2015 :P

Answer (score 1):

I guess:

## August 22nd, 2015

Answer (score 1):

August 8 2015

No real reason, it's my father's b-day :D

Answer (score 1):

I'll go for, 2015-08-17. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 1):

Million ends at n. n is the 14th letter in the standard english alphabet series. 1+4 is 5. 5th letter in the same series is e. e is the second letter in meta. 2 is the fourth digit of the id of the regex tony the pony answer (1732454). The answer was posted on November 13, 2009. That day was Monday. The 4th monday of august 2015 is on 23rd day of the month and 3 days later is 26th.

Hence proved, 10th million question will be posted on 26th August 2015.

No need to clap.

Comment: Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå still claimed the slot, so this guess / proof cannot count.

Comment: @MartijnPieters edited. Didn't realize when I posted that dupes aren't allowed.

Comment: That's the problem with predicting a specific day, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to predict **August 1, 2015**, because I prefer the month of August to the month of July.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this there are 9,763,271 questions which means we have 236,729 to go.  I estimate what we do 6,750 question per day that actually make it about 24 hours.  figure we lose another 15% that s 5740 question per day.  using that we would get 8/23.

## So my pick will be **9/2** as it is the next open day.

Comment: i like how the `math` answers have similar calculations, yet different dates :)

Comment: @ericosg Same algorithm with different data gives different answers.

Answer (score -1):

## 2015-08-13

Just to fill that gap in the middle of the other guesses :-)

Too bad it's not even a Friday...

Answer (score -1):

Factoring in a possible increase in questions leading up to it, the unclaimed days remaining, and a lot of guesswork, I'll guess...

## 8-2-15

Answer (score -1):

### August 24, 2015

There's a nice little gap in the list that needs filling :)

Answer (score -1):

September 1, 2015

8k per day is aug 24, plus another 8 days to accommodate for deletions.

It will probably be a question tagged with javascript containing a 100 line code dump. Do we get bonus shwag for getting the accepted answer on #10M? :)

Comment: I shouldn't have adjusted for deletions :(

Answer (score -1):

## October 7, 2015

For no other reason than the first date to pop in my head. I checked Wikipedia and nothing seemed to jump out at me on a quick glance.

Comment: Why was this down voted? I wrote an answer like everyone else.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going for:

### 6th November 2015

Don't ask for the logic ;)

Comment: Cause it's my birthday, it's my birthday, and we gonna' party like it's my birthday.

Comment: @OhBeWise lol I'll remember to say happy birthday on the 6th ;) BTW Please could you edit into the question my prediction? I don't have enough rep, so can't even suggest an edit! :(

Comment: @OhBeWise Martin Smith did it! :)

Comment: @OhBeWise Happy birthday!! :P

Comment: Haha! Thanks! Didn't expect that.

Answer (score -1):

I guess:

## 2015-09-10

I just have a feeling.

Comment: I edited your entry into the question's list of taken dates.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thanks! I guess I just forgot that I could do it myself. :)

Answer (score -1):

2015-09-12

I believe it will be the day before but this is the closest I can choose.

Answer (score -2):

I'm going for:

**August 28, 2015.**

Comment: I made a pretty bad error in my calculations.

Comment: I realized a while ago, but haven't got round to making a calculation of my own. It was more a joke tbh

Answer (score -2):

### The 10 Millionth question will occur on the day in which the 9 Million 9 Hundred Ninety Nine Thousand Nine hundred Ninety Ninth question is asked

Do not ask me how I know this.

If that does not get me some more Stack Overflow swag, I do not know what will.

---

> Time is relative to the question (and the answer) so giving an actual date/time on the calendar will always be wrong ;-)

Comment: Time is relative to the question (and the answer) so giving an **actual** date/time on the calendar will always be wrong ;-)

Comment: The 10^5th question could be asked at precisely 0:00, while the (10^5)-1th question could be asked at precisely 23:59:59.999.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I accounted for that with wibbly wobbly time variations on my original calculations that led me to believe that it is possible for the 10M question actually get asked BEFORE the 9,999,999th question due to time differences and internet speeds.

Answer (score -2):

I think Ill go for **9/11** ...

for no....

apparent reasons....

Comment: Don't forget to mark your entry in the question.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Indeed!Forgot to do it, thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Looking at the [current questions / day rate](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic) against how many we still need before reaching 10 million, I'm guessing that it'll take another 4 weeks.

So my guess, futzing in a little acceleration towards the end:

### Thursday, August 6, 2015

Comment: -1 When measuring in weeks, the answer is always 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @AwalGarg: knock yourself out! There are still slots available in the 22-29 August range available. :-P

Comment: This is the date my highly scientific calculations arrived at (adjusting for bloodstains).

Answer (score -3):

I think that we will hit that on October 03, 2015. Nay, I know.

Answer (score -3):

I want to say **10/11** because **Walking Dead**, but my incredibly sloppy and probably incorrect calculations based on the average rate of questions asked per week puts it later in the month.

### I say 10/21

Answer (score -3):

**September Third, 2015**.

That seems about right to me.

Answer (score -3):

**October 12, 2015**

I hope I win the box of swag. I need a box.

Comment: If Slapout wins s/he should be sent a box inside a box inside a box .... inside a box ... with the most inner  box bottom having the word SWAG on it.

Comment: And when it arrives, it should be smashed with a hammer!

Answer (score -3):

**September 4th, 2015**
a.k.a
**09/04/2015**

...Because all of the other answers I wanted were taken.

Answer (score -3):

**September 5th, 2015**

Because every day prior that I wanted was taken.

Answer (score -3):

I'll go with:

> 010100110110010101110000011101000110010101101101011000100110010101110010001000000011000100110011001011000010000000110010001100000011000100110101

or September 13, 2015. It coincides with the next scheduled [Solar Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_September_13,_2015).

Answer (score -3):

I'll take

## September 6, 2015

please!

Answer (score -3):

**2015 July 29**

Because Microsoft will release Windows 10 that day.

Answer (score -3):

**October 26th 2015.**

That's the third year I met my girlfriend

Comment: you better share the swag with her if you win then

Comment: @Dronehinge yeah, of course.

Answer (score -4):

August 31 by some unsuspecting new user who will ask a very mediocre question that may or may not have been previously answered.

Comment: Oh that was I typo

Answer (score -4):

## August 30, 2015 (2015-08-30)

A random guess ;-)

Answer (score -5):

## Future.

Comment: VTC: Too broad ;D

Comment: @AwalGarg: By that sense you should be closing the question for having too many possible answers, not my answer :)

Comment: your answer becomes deprecated after the 10th mil question happens

Comment: @Dronehinge: Would you like "Somewhere on the timeline" instead?

Comment: ***o.0 NOT ENOUGH JQUERY***

Answer (score -5):

## 2015-07-30T18:00Z

... probably.

Answer (score -5):

## 2015-08-06

I haven't seen a wrong answer of Martijn's yet.

Comment: You have now...

Answer (score -5):

I will throw in a claim for July 31st

Answer (score -5):

## September 9th 2015 (9-09-15)

Using <s>random numbers</s> math formulas, this date is what seems to work. Plus the good dates are taken.

Answer (score -5):

When: ***Aug 20 '15 at ~9 AM***

Comment: looks like we have a winner! although you're a good fake... a good one.

Answer (score -7):

Its going to be on the 20 of August 2015:

2015-08-20

<sub>I apologise for cheating and answering when we are ~4000 questions to go.</sub>

Comment: Jeremy's already got their name down (ages ago) I'm afraid :)