# Should historically locked questions count toward 10M questions milestone?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone, historical-lock

In the context of the competition [Let's predict the date of the ten millionth question on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299058/lets-predict-the-date-of-the-ten-millionth-question-on-stack-overflow?lq=1) I'd like to clarify which count of questions should be used. There are two:

- [/questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest)
- [/info method](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info#filter=!GeC7Pt-VqTbMH&site=stackoverflow&run=true) of the API

The former excludes historically locked questions; the latter includes all questions. (I confirmed this behavior after comparing the two counts for other sites.)

Which count should be used for the purpose of determining the time of reaching 10M questions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not that this is particularly important, but hey - if we're gonna have a bit of self-indulgent vanity, we might as well be *precise* when focusing in on our collective navel.

So... In my humble opinion, the count on /questions should be used.

Primarily because it's the one everyone *sees*, but also because philosophically Historical Lock questions are **deleted** - and we don't count deleted questions in either place.