# 10 million questions or 10 million GOOD questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, 10m-questions-milestone

Stack Overflow's hit [10 million questions](https://stackoverflow.com/10m). Yay.

[image: SO's celebratory logo variant]

I'm curious, though; what does the question count actually include? Does it include closed and downvoted questions? Because in my favourite tags over 50% of the new questions I see every day are not actually useful to anybody. So I was just wondering.

Comment: Nowhere near 10 million [good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/21/good-question).

Comment: It *doesn't* include deleted questions (which closed/DVd ones tend to become). I think it includes closed questions which haven't been deleted yet.

Comment: Assuming [Sturgeon's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon's_law), we're at about 1 million questions that aren't crap.

Comment: I'm also hitting 100k on this day itself :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Congratulations!

Comment: Depends on what you consider "good" I guess.

Comment: Yay, SO reached 10m questions because it's being flooded with crap every day! And everybody knows that quantity is the most important metric anyways, nobody cares that milions of those questions are low quality duplicates, typos, people too lazy to read the docs, and so on. So let's all celebrate by tweeting `#SOreadytohelp`. Because we're a help site! /Facepalm...

Comment: ...and you recieved a troll answer on your GOOD question /facepalm...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Could you please a href link to [hit 10 million](http://stackoverflow.com/10m)

Comment: @l4mpi: It's the most accessible objective measure available. Which is also [why we are all paid by the line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324399/what-is-a-fair-productivity-measurement-technique-for-programmers). ;-()

Comment: @Mysticial Sturgeon's law may say that 90% is crap, it doesn't say that the remaining 10% isn't.  I'd interpret it as a lower boundary.

Comment: This is no different than Apple saying they have X billion apps in the app store (how many of those are good?) or Twitter saying they have X trillion tweets (how many of *those* are GOOD?!). Volume, while not a measurement of quality, is certainly still a measurement of success.

Comment: @Mysticial quote from the link, "Sturgeon's revelation, commonly inaccurately referred to as Sturgeon's law"...

Comment: @remus: Depends on how you define "success", I suppose.

Comment: Is your question is a good or bad one ?

Comment: What's a GOOD question? The upvote count is no clear indicator. Even questions with 100 upvotes can be totally simple (In the shell, how do I test whether a file exists?) or downright silly (In C, what does the --> operator do?).

Comment: I have no problems with the question quality criteria for celebration.  One has to get bad questions to get good questions. However, the correct *count* is 12,345,678.9.

Comment: @http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1110381/l4mpi
Yes, it IS a help site. And for no reason you wasted energy for facepalming :)

Comment: @1000Gbps: No, it's not.

Comment: Seriously now, hundreds of thousands of good questions. That's still pretty impressive. Now how about the number of _answered_ questions...

Comment: But the fact remains that nobody would waste their time to write a question here with all the formatting, if it's not useful to them. And if something's useful for them, then logically, it should be useful to their coworkers, or better yet, other people.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit
"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming."

With >>>YOUR<<< help!

Questions usually contain a problem(s). Anwsers of the people around here solve them.

Comment: @1000 Your rationale is equivalent to saying that "With your help, we can reach Mars by 2030" means NASA is a help site.

Comment: @Orbit ... Charities are exactly that - raising money for funding the researches which help the people
Edit2: NASA get the money from Government, and people pay taxes so the gov has enough money for funding and helping people to reach the stars :)

Comment: StackOverFlow is the definition of a help site...

Comment: @AntónioPaulo: You are mistaken.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet So what is StackOverFlow? Is a site meant go gain points? Stackoverflow helps everyone here. If you have a question you can search for it or even ask yourself. Even if you don't have question, you can answer and improve your profile because it helps if you need a job. Imagine if Jon Skeet wasn't on Google, that profile gives him any job he wants.

Comment: @AntónioPaulo: Not everything that helps you is a "help site". Like, a dictionary is also not a "help site". Stack Overflow (not "StackOverFlow") is a repository of questions and answers, each one deliberately being of benefit to multiple people, both now and in the future. Of course, reading questions and answers is a helpful process. But calling it a "help site" makes it sound like each question is _just for that asker_. It's not. When it's like that, quality sinks to oblivion. SO was deliberately founded to _not_ use that model.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet When you answer a question, you are not helping? When you ask someone, don't you ask it waiting for any help? If a website is based in a question/answer "game", it's meant to help, it was build to help someone.

Comment: @AntónioPaulo: I already addressed that. That help is ultimately rendered does not make it a help site.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet So what's the purpose of Stack?

Comment: @AntónioPaulo: Read my previous comments ^^^^ And it's "Stack Overflow", not "Stack".

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I guess we have different opinions.. and people like to make things as short as possible when typing, so that's why I wrote Stack.

Comment: @AntónioPaulo: SO's goals and policies are not a matter of opinion; they are a matter of record.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I'll say it again, we have different opinions. What is the point of record all this data?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The /questions page   excludes historically locked questions, since they are not seen when browsing that page. ([Reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302851)) Everything else is included.

As of now, there are [9,152,194 non-closed questions with non-negative score](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A0+score%3A0..), so by this measure, the celebration appears slightly premature.

Comment: I'm surprised it's that much. Well, I suppose auto-deletion takes care of it?

Comment: I can't decide if I'm impressed or depressed that about 91% of SO questions are "good" according to this... :(

Comment: @enderland: [Probably impressed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law) Or skeptical. Your call.

Comment: @JonEricson it's like the 80/20 principle, backwards!

Comment: @enderlandL The [Pareto principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) does apply here too: 20% (or whatever) of the questions get 80% (or whatnot) of the votes. [citation needed]

Comment: And 4.5 million questions with a positive score.  How good is "good"?

Comment: how many of the 10M questions are non-closed with negative score?

Comment: @enderland 91% of the *currently existing questions*.  Closed questions with negative score eventually get auto-deleted by the system.  This answer says nothing about the ratio of "good questions" (non-closed with non-negative score) to "not good questions" (closed or negative score) because the vast majority of "not good questions" end up auto-deleted and only SE employees could tell us how many deleted questions there are.

Answer (score 14):

How to define good questions anyway? I've read questions that are downvoted and they helped me. Sometimes questions are downvoted because they are not formatted or for the lack of research, or because of being duplicates, but as for me, a regular user, all I care about is the answer.

Bad questions affects the quality of the website and also make it hard for users to help the OP, but it doesn't matter for people who google it; sometimes they find good answers too. So in a way or another, bad questions are still helping users, therefore helping the site grow.

I would argue that bad questions sometimes help more than good ones, the googlers. Because I'm more likely as a Python guy to want to know how to fix [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127903/runtime-error-with-python-dictionary-while-using-defaultdict) than to know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796910/how-does-python-know-what-to-do-with-the-in-keyword). Sure the first is silly and the second is interesting, but when I'm programming I won't really care about the second. Fixing the first is a priority, and I would probably read the second while scrolling on Stack Overflow, if I have nothing else to do.

I bet that there are more unregistered or inactive users on Stack Overflow each day than active users. Those users want their issues to be solved. Downvotes or upvotes, they don't care, if the answer solves their problem. It's a good question from their point of view, because it was their question too.

Comment: -15, really? Questioning our values in terms of question quality should not be punished, in my opinion, and it is definitely on topic when the original question is drawing comments about the quality of the 10K questions. I hope @Lynob does not delete this. Props to Peter M for cleaning up the question though, sloppy grammar is worth downvotes.

Comment: I was going to write a similar answer and so I appreciate @Lynob's effort.  most people think I am ugly, my wife thinks I am handsome.  There are lots of questions that I have seen that have been downvoted, shot at etc where either the question made me think about my issue a different way or one or more of the answers was spot on for what I needed.  Maybe we should have a SO lite and and then one for the rest of them.  My guess is that the programming  'geniuses' who sometimes get real picky would still be around if their rep transferred even if they were not allowed to dv  on the SO lite site

Comment: @DanRoss Note: **on meta** upvote and downvote can just mean "I agree" or "I disagree". In this case I disagree with his examples, as the first one isn't closed and has both answers and a linked duplicate (which is higher quality and has the best answer out of the two). While, though he is correct that the second question can be very interesting to developers but not as pertinent to an actual project - *he fails to take into account* that this is reflected if you look at the duplicate as it has a rep of 100 and the second question only has a rep of 29.

Comment: @JGreenwell sorry about the examples, I picked random example to prove a point, and didn't read it. I was trying to showcase a random example to prove a point, too late to change the example, if you see the point I'm trying to make, that's all that matters to me.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I use lesser "quality" Q&A for getting work done many times a day. I do not contribute "canonical" questions/answers and rarely *use* them either.  Although they should be  applauded - they already get more than enough positive press.  Mostly the questions  I find personally  useful on a regular basis are about edge cases and  smaller misconceptions. The answers to those questions are rarely high score but frequently vital to progress.

Answer (score 11):

In my opinion, two important ways we can measure the quality of questions are:

1. Was the question well received by the community? Proxies for this would be the question's score and whether or not it's closed.
2. Was the question useful to the world at large? A proxy for this would be the question's view count.

Limiting to the 9.12 million questions in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer with a question score of at least 0 and that are not closed, we can look at the distribution of the score and view count (note the log scale on both axes):

[image]

The questions returned by the query are concentrated at score 0 (the bottom row of hexagons) and view count of roughly 100. In total, 1.96 million questions (21%) have score 0 and no more than 100 views, and 4.13 million questions (45%) have score 0 and no more than 1,000 views.

Summarizing, about 850k questions are closed or have negative score, and nearly 2 million additional questions have score 0 and no more than 100 views. While some of these low-score, low-view questions may be in low-traffic tags or may have been posted quite recently, I think the data show that there's a sizable number of questions that haven't been well received by the SO community or the world at large.

**Methodology:**

I grabbed the number of questions with each score/view count combination from the Stack Exchange Data Explorer with the following query:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(LOG10(ViewCount+1)*100, 0)/100, Score, COUNT(*) from Posts
  WHERE PostTypeId=1 AND ClosedDate IS NULL
  GROUP BY ROUND(LOG10(ViewCount+1)*100, 0)/100, Score;
```

The rounding of the (log-transformed) view count ensures that the query returns fewer than 50,000 rows, the limit for the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. Storing the query result in `dat.csv`, I ran the following R code to process the data:

```r
# Read data, transforming so we have one row per question
dat <- read.csv("dat.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat[,1] <- round(10^(dat[,1])-1)
names(dat) <- c("ViewCount", "Score", "Count")
dat <- dat[rep(1:nrow(dat), dat$Count), c("ViewCount", "Score")]
dat <- dat[dat$Score >= 0,]

# Plot view count vs. score
library(ggplot2)
print(ggplot(dat, aes(x=ViewCount+1, y=Score+1)) + stat_binhex(bins=15) +
      scale_x_log10("Number of Views (plus one)", breaks=10^(0:6), labels=c("1", "10", "100", "1k", "10k", "100k", "1m")) +
      scale_y_log10("Score (plus one)", breaks=10^(0:4), labels=c("1", "10", "100", "1k", "10k")) +
      theme_bw())

# Summarize questions with low views and score
sum(dat$Score == 0 & dat$ViewCount <= 100)
mean(dat$Score == 0 & dat$ViewCount <= 100)
sum(dat$Score == 0 & dat$ViewCount <= 1000)
mean(dat$Score == 0 & dat$ViewCount <= 1000)
```

Comment: Excellent work! What's your conclusion?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit buried at the end: "I think the data show that there's a sizable number of questions that haven't been well received by the SO community or the world at large."

Comment: Oh right was wondering whether you had a rough figure in conclusion. Not to worry!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ah, now I understand. Of course, it totally depends on how you define a "good" question." If we define good questions as those that are not closed and either have positive score or more than 100 views, then we have about 7.16 million good questions.

Comment: It may be interesting to look at individual examples of the best questions in "score per thousand views". This is the [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/553820/hidden-gems-highest-question-score-per-thousand-views-minimum-1-000-views) for a minimum of 1,000 views; there seems to be a natural limit at arround 100 score points per 1,000 views. With [no view threshold](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/551081/hidden-gems-highest-question-score-per-thousand-views), extreme examples appear at ratio 1,000: typically, score 1 and 1 view.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it includes closed and downvoted questions, but it does not include deleted question.

You can refer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302851/should-historically-locked-questions-count-toward-10m-questions-milestone), where @Shog9♦ mentioned that deleted questions are not included in total count.

If you refer to [this closed and downvoted question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1%20inquestion%3A32124532), and this question is also listed in [main question list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest)(without tag filter) which shows a count towards 10M, so it means downvoted and closed questions are included in the 10M list right now.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide any references to back up your answer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - If you run a query on [`is:question`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion), you get the 10 million figure, and can see counted in that list downvoted or closed questions. Deleted questions (of which there are 2,584,855 at present) are not in that list.

Comment: @Brad: Okay so roughly a ratio of, what, 9:4 good to closed-or-deleted questions by my count. Empirically to me it seems like we need to close and delete more ;P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit :- If you click on the question button(without tag filter) on SO main page, the you are able to see the count more then 10M, and it inlcudes downvoted and closed question over there

Comment: The purpose was to find a reference for the assertion that "it includes downvoted and closed question".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit :- I don't think, SO have that documented somewhere, but if I get, will post it here

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit :- see the edit answer to reference for "it includes downvoted and closed question"

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName: I have reverted your edit to the question. The spelling "favourite" is correct.

Answer (score -4):

A [basic query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+votes%3A2..+locked%3Ano) to filter out a lot of crap:

> is:q closed:no votes:2.. locked:no

2.4M results.

Adding some negative keywords, the best query I could come up with is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+votes%3A2..+-thanks+-thx+-please+-pls+-suggest+-edit+-u+-urgent+-%22a+doubt%22+-informations+-spit+-cuz+-coz+-skills+-lol+-librarys+-%22couldnt%22+-teh+-wat+-tanks+-newbie+-noob+-n00b+-%22guide+me%22+-%22refer+http%3A%2F%2F%22+-%22any+ideas%22+locked%3Ano):

> is:q closed:no votes:2.. -thanks -thx -please -pls -suggest -edit -u -urgent -"a doubt" -informations -spit -cuz -coz -skills -lol -librarys -"couldnt" -teh -wat -tanks -newbie -noob -n00b -expert -"guide me" -"refer http://" -"any ideas" locked:no

1.5M results. [~96.5%](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A1+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+votes%3A2..+-thanks+-thx+-please+-pls+-suggest+-edit+-u+-urgent+-%22a+doubt%22+-informations+-spit+-cuz+-coz+-skills+-lol+-librarys+-%22couldnt%22+-teh+-wat+-tanks+-newbie+-noob+-n00b+-%22guide+me%22+-%22refer+http%3A%2F%2F%22+-%22any+ideas%22+locked%3Ano) have 1 or more answers, [~61%](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A2+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+votes%3A2..+-thanks+-thx+-please+-pls+-suggest+-edit+-u+-urgent+-%22a+doubt%22+-informations+-spit+-cuz+-coz+-skills+-lol+-librarys+-%22couldnt%22+-teh+-wat+-tanks+-newbie+-noob+-n00b+-%22guide+me%22+-%22refer+http%3A%2F%2F%22+-%22any+ideas%22+locked%3Ano) have 2 or more answers.

So we have about 500k helpful on-topic Q/A pairs.

Comment: ONLY 2M??/?// YOU DOOMED THE WORLD!!11!1!!!

Comment: Don't forget "guide me" and "refer http://"

Comment: So, containing fluff like "thanks" or typos like "teh" somehow disqualifies a question from being helpful?  Plus other things like "any ideas"?  Or "expert"?  I'm not sure how it even remotely makes sense that some of the phrases you've included automatically make a question entirely unhelpful.

Comment: @nhgrif There is an extremely tiny number of false negatives; false positives are much more of a problem as there is no simple way to filter them out. Obviously, this query is very inaccurate. But most questions which have those keywords are of significantly lower quality than those with, so it at least gives us a starting point for a list of high-quality questions. The only tools really that we have to determine post quality is a) votes (which gives a disadvantage to low-traffic tags), b) structure (which can't be covered in a query), and c) keywords (which can only correlate with quality).