# How many questions have been deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, statistics

How many questions are deleted on SO per day?

For our currently reached [10m-questions-milestone](/questions/tagged/10m-questions-milestone) only the non-deleted questions are counted. [Not all of them are good questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302925/1048572), but I'm curious: How many questions were so bad that they got deleted?

The [`delete` tab of the review tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days) shows me the most recently deleted posts (including answers, which seem to be much more frequent), but only the last 45 or so. There are no stats about deletions, neither long- nor short term.

I'm not interested in which questions those were (some of them can be found in [the archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124850/183280)), but only for the numbers. How many questions were deleted altogether? How many questions are deleted per day/week/month, how did this change over time? How many of these were roombaed automatically or deleted by user votes explicitly, how many of them by their own respectively? How many were deleted within hours of posting, how many were days old? If possible, posts that were deleted because of spam flags should be excluded from the numbers.

Comment: The mod-only search `deleted:1 is:question` says about 2.6 million.

Comment: @BoltClock: I guessed you had the tools for that :-) Does it allow you to break the number further down?

Comment: Last 5 days of deletions: 616, 733, 786, 779, 450 apparently (counts based on post creation date, not deletion date). By last active date (which I imagine is going to be as close to the deletion date as poss.) - it's 652, 759, 795, 779, 468. Anything more complicated will require a dev to run a report :)

Comment: Important to note that the cleanup scripts run as scheduled tasks, so it might seem like a _whole_ lot of stuff gets deleted at once, when in fact it's just deleting questions that gained no traction _whatsoever_ (or a negative response altogether, without any upvoted answers). So when you see the deletion dates in contrast to the last activity and it looks odd, that's why.

Comment: FWIW [stats for Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6507/provide-10k-users-more-close-votes#comment22631_7534) say on average 18 of 46 questions are deleted every day

Comment: [Different sites have different overall long-term deletion rates](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/6744).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221337/around-how-many-questions-get-deleted-in-stack-exchange-and-by-who/221493#221493

Comment: @BoltClock, Is the 2.6 million counted as part of the [10 million](http://stackoverflow.com/10m)?

Comment: @Pacerier No. Deleted questions were not counted. Closed questions, negatively scored questions, were counted though.

Answer (score 8):

There are by this day 2,893,599 questions deleted.

That number is obtained from [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415186#graph). The table PostsWithDeleted was added in [Sep, 16th 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/158100).

Using the Graph result you get this picture for counts per day:

[image: deleted counts per day]

Notice how in the weekend the roomba script runs and that deletes up to 9,000 questions while on normal days between 1,000 and 1,500 questions are deleted.

I assume you can take it from here to add the per week, month and year counts.