# Please correct the dead link on the locked post

Tags: support, hyperlinks, historical-lock

Since it's [not possible to flag, edit or report locked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190360/191655), I'm reporting the issue here.

This post: [What is the worst programming language you ever worked with? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/962146/55075)

has the following dead link:

```
http://www.php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html#unicode
```

I'd like to correct the link to the archived one which exists:

> http://web.archive.org/web/20131021103044/http://www.php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html#unicode

Comment: It's locked specifically to indicate that it's not a post that's going to be kept up to date, because it doesn't belong on the site.

Comment: What value was seen in that question that it deserved a historical lock? It's basically a list of outdated cons about every language in existence.

Comment: Hey look, it's another post proving that historical locks *make no sense at all*.

Comment: I don't like clicking on the dead links. If it's public for historical purposes, so I would expect at least some links to be working, so I can read about it more (about PHP in this case). Especially if it's a simple change. I believe this post is useful, but I'd like to correct the link. After correction, theoretically the link should work forever.

Comment: @animuson can you delete it? The question was considered off-topic even back in 2009, there's no reason it should have lived on for 7 years.

Comment: I'm against deleting either. [Archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20160825195618/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961942/what-is-the-worst-programming-language-you-ever-worked-with/) just in case.

Comment: "philosophically Historical Lock questions are **deleted**" ([Should historically locked questions count toward 10M questions milestone?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302852/839601))

Comment: ...is Stack Exchange management wasn't that fixated on futile attempts to force regulars _be nice_ to help vampires, they could spend 3-4 hours of dev time to [make pink background when rendering historically locked posts](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7828/31260) so that wrong / broken links would become obviously irrelevant to any reader with brains

Answer (score 22):

That question just isn't valuable at all.  Not only is fixing that one link just not important, the whole question just isn't a useful resource.  That question should just be deleted.

Comment: @TravisJ locked question :(

Comment: @TravisJ You should note that [tag:del-vote-plz] isn't a thing here. were [tag:del-pls] makes sense elsewhere. I'm never going to invite you for a coffee again, whenever meeting you. You completely screwed that up.