# Is a historical lock really appropriate when there are plenty of questions closed as duplicates of it?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, historical-lock

A small reminder about what is an **historically locked** question:

- It's considered to be [a **deleted** question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302851/should-historically-locked-questions-count-toward-10m-questions-milestone/302852#302852), but visible to all.
- It has no FLAG/DELETE/EDIT/VOTE buttons (so you can't improve it, can't remove it, can't report it).
- It's different from a **Locked** question.

But recently I found: *[How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)*. It is used as a target for many duplicates, even recent ones ([354 linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/9605913?lq=1)). Considering there is clearly activity on Stack Overflow on the topic of parsing JSON in Android, I'm not sure if the historical lock is the correct status that the question deserves.

- With this abundance of duplicates, shouldn't the historical lock be replaced with a normal lock, like in *[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)*?
- If the answer is "*No, keep it with a historical lock to prevent any improvement possible*", then are there anything we should do regarding the many duplicates? For instance, should we work at deleting those duplicates of a post explicitly considered deleted ([as recommended by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43724/duplicate-of-deleted-post))?

Comment: That people are using it as a duplicate is a shame. The question is far too broad even with the rosiest of colored glasses to be useful.

Comment: Those lock types just don't have anything in common, despite the name.  A normal lock prevents adding answers, a historical lock prevents deleting the answers.  Intention is to preserve those answers, that the question is hopelessly broad is no longer relevant.  Do note that it is the top Google hit for "android how to parse json", how it got 400K views, they always did like broad questions.  Albeit that pinning the YouTube movie to the top probably was divine intervention :)  The [android] tag had a severe content moderation problem back then, not so sure it recovered from that.

Comment: @TinyGiant actually there is a miss understand, people think that 
 duplicate is for question. This is not true, duplicate is for answer, two questions can be different but have been mark as duplicate, because the answer are the same.

Answer (score 17):

"Where can I find step-by-step instructions on..." is not a great question for Stack Overflow, but a really great answer kept that question alive. It probably should just be edited to "How do I..." so that the existing good answers can stand, the lock can be changed, and the remaining link-only answer can be deleted. (I don't know why the moderator who locked it didn't do this years ago.)

Comment: Currently, the historical lock prevents it to be edited to "_How do I..._". Maybe another moderator will support your answer and help?

Comment: *a really great answer* yes and no. It can certainly help out new developers, but it is horribly outdated and does not reflect 'modern' ways of doing it. The suggested way to "get the json" will not even work, because the library that the answer uses was removed from the sdk 2 years ago

Comment: @TimCastelijns In that case, the lock should probably be removed instead of changed, that way new answers can be added without breaking all the incoming links.

Comment: or it can be deleted altogether. I don't know what would happen to questions currently closed as duplicates of it or how cases like this are normally handed, but having 354 questions link to wrong information can't be optimal. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) question can be a replacement to close future questions against. It currently has no android tag, but the answers apply to both java and android

Comment: I've unlocked it, edited the question, removed the bad answer, and cleaned up a few of the comments there. Should be free for anyone else to improve this further.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I can't easily verify that that answer is outdated, but now that the question is unlocked, closing it as a duplicate should point people to the other question.