# Stack Overflow title edit to 'celebrate' 10 million questions

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone, logo

[image]

Took me a little bit to understand the new title (the title was updated and published prior to the explanation being displayed..)

I'm guessing it will just stick around for the day?

Link to the [Celebratory (blog?) Post](https://stackoverflow.com/10m)

[Prediction thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299058/lets-predict-the-date-of-the-ten-millionth-question-on-stack-overflow) for the 10 millionth post

Comment: Came here to find out why the title is what it is. Thanks!

Comment: was the "Ten. Million. Questions. Let's celebrate all we've done together." not a clue?

Comment: @Guinness When I copied the image, it didn't have the description :)

Comment: It would be great if they pulled a Google and made the new logo link to an explanation, instead of adding an explanatory banner below the logo *minutes after the logo change* cc @GuinnessIsLife I had enough time to WTF around on chat for a few minutes before the banner appeared.

Comment: Just need somebody to come in here about how the new SO logo with the multiple O's violates his brand's devotion to a single O and to post a long disclosure about it.

Comment: Tune in here tomorrow. Copious amounts of fun and swag shall be had by all that want to participate :) I'm not sure what they were thinking when they made me a manager.

Comment: @TimPost so it's a party-cipation tomorrow?

Comment: They should have saved that title image for the googolth question.

Comment: Was trying to search to find this question (knew it *had* to be on Meta already) but couldn't find it due to not being able to figure out what to search (if I'd known to search 10 million questions, I wouldn't have needed to search lol). Of course now that I've taken the time to find this and type this comment the explanation is displayed for me. At least I know.

Comment: @TimPost There's a spelling mistake on the page: "That's about the entire **popultion** of LA, Chicago,..."

Comment: @DavidSherret Pushing a fix now, thank you!

Comment: @null Nah, the logo would have to say stackoverfloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooow for the googolth question posted. (I'd love to see *that*, but it won't happen in my lifetime unfortunately :( )

Comment: Neat! Pathetically, I didn't even notice it until now...

Comment: @TimPost another one: "Not a fan of __teh__ twitters?" or was that intentional?

Comment: @SleuthEye I'd hazard a guess that it was indeed intentional.

Comment: Am I the only person who keeps seeing the 10,000,000 banner in the corner of their eye and thinks that their monitor is dirty?! o_O It's like happened about a dozen times this am. Who decided gray on gray was a good idea?

Comment: also, congrats... :P

Comment: going to buy the stackoverflooooooow.com domain ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The  [/10M](https://stackoverflow.com/10M) page'll be up at least a month, because it's completely out of the way, and we're giving stuff away for four weeks.  Plus it's kind of fun to guess what each live number will change to next, and then feel really good about yourself when you're right.

[image]

The logo change and celebration banner will come down sooner. We'll likely take that down within a week or so out the outside, but may re-run  a modified version of it each week to let folks know there's another shot at improving their wardrobe.

Comment: I get that the background of the banner is supposed to represent a network or graph, but it just made me think my screen was dirty, which is annoying...

Comment: For a while I thought the commas were dirt specs too. Maybe it's just me, but you might want to bump their size up just a little.

Comment: @McBrainy & 4444, you guys must have pretty dirty screens if that's your first thought!

Comment: @Dave I had a thunderbug in my screen last week... thought it had bred!

Comment: Are you sure those numbers are actually live? The dev tools in my browser aren't showing any network requests when they update...

Comment: How long before someone in some European country complains because you've used comma separators in the logo rather than points?

Comment: @McBrainy I agree. In fact, the weird background annoyed me so much that I blocked it with AdBlock :)

Comment: @Ajedi32 It's using a web socket to transmit the data, open the Dev Tools and reload while filtering WebSockets. http://i.stack.imgur.com/NocIr.png

Comment: a whooooooole moooooooth? oooooooh nooooooo .... please nooooooot!

Comment: Banner?  What banner?  When I come here, it's usually via Google (that was/is one of the factors for getting a site out of beta, IIRC), and then there is no banner.

Comment: I agree with @McBrainy and 4444, the font of "thousand separator" do not fit well with "overfloooow" font text. And it is bit annoying. A bold dot can be more appropriate. Since "." (dot) also a separator in other locales/languages.

Comment: I simply found the color on the bottom part of that 10M page to be visually offensive - the area with all the faces.  That bright red/orange was irritating.  I got off the page as quick as I could because of it.  If you are going to keep it up for a month, at least change the color of that part.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard you are basically passive for 2 1/2 years so...

Comment: So what? What are *trying* to say?

Comment: @UlukBiy I prefer commas. Dots would confuse many Americans. Maybe it could be locale-based though.

Answer (score -6):

**"We'll likely take that down within a week or so out the outside"**

That sounded like a **good idea**.

Just as an abstract question that comes to mind, say you have some online acquaintances who have a fun little startup,

but are doing something embarrassing and immature with their web presence, what's the best way to, err, **hint** to them to, err, take down the banner that's been there *way* too long?!

Comment: Thank goodness, the embarrassing banner has been finally removed. So this is now moot.