# How do you notify a typo on 10-million questions page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10m-questions-milestone

It looks like there's a tiny typo on 10-million questions page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/10m).

It never happened to me on SO to contact staff to notify a typo/bug/similar. How do you do that?

`popultion`
-->
`population`

Sorry if meta is not the right place to ask.

Comment: Tim Post says a fix is being pushed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302923/stack-overflow-title-edit-to-celebrate-10-million-questions?noredirect=1#comment236142_302923


Is it possible to direct-link to a comment? Not sure if I remember having seen that before

Comment: @Trobbins The timestamp of a comment gives you a link to it.

Comment: @Kendra ah, of course, thanks for the reminder!

[Direct-link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302923/stack-overflow-title-edit-to-celebrate-10-million-questions?noredirect=1#comment236142_302923) to the comment.