# "Ten. Million. Questions." message looks dirty

Tags: discussion, user-interface, 10m-questions-milestone

I was totally sure that my screen was dirty when I saw this message for the first time. I know that all these gray dots in the background represent something, but they look like a dirty screen, *especially* on the right side. Is it only my personal feeling, or does that banner need a cleanup?

[image: Banner screenshot]

The issue was [noticed earlier by @McBrainy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302923/stack-overflow-title-edit-to-celebrate-10-million-questions#comment236316_302940):

[image: Comment screenshot]

Comment: I second this. It's understandable that the designer used a light grey tone to keep the text readable, however the result doesn't look good in my opinion (dirty / dusty). How about the orange tone used in the 10m page? If the graph is only displayed to the right of the text it would not interfere with its readability.

Comment: Lol, I hadn't noticed this until I read this question.

Comment: Am I the only one who was really confused by how "Ten. Million. Questions" had been subjected to Rule 34?

Comment: I thought the same thing (that my screen was dirty), but not because of the "Ten. Million. Questions." message. I thought the commas in the `stackoverflo,ooo,ooow` logo were hairs!

Comment: Agreed. Don't like it at all. It does weird things to my eyes that make it hard to look at the site.

Comment: Well... the problem is that the designer probably has a good display while most people have a cheap TN Panel. It looks fine on my monitor.
That said he could've seen that one coming and used more contrast.

Comment: On my MacBook Air it largely depends on the angle.

Comment: Rule 34... ? Ah, dirty as in pornographic. Gotcha. Took me a bit.

Comment: Hehe I debated posting a question about this on the day. But decided there was too much risk of being flamed....

Comment: My screen is so dirty that I didn't even notice the network in the background at first.

Comment: Maybe the designer wanted everyone to hopelessly clean and re-clean their screens.

Comment: Nooooo! I never noticed until now! Now I can't not notice

Comment: +1 because I actually tried to wipe my screen the first time I saw that banner. :-/

Comment: Thank god, I thought I was the only one. Blocking the background image made everything better again.

Comment: Exactly what I thought the very first moment I saw that banner!

Comment: On top of that it gave me the false impression that I was not logged in yet.

Comment: @WayneWerner: Here is your obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/305/

Comment: This is torturous. I'm so irritated about the dirt simulation that my hands are literally shaking. No joke. lol.

Comment: @demonkoryu Possibly that's low blood sugar, take care.

Comment: Am I the only one who isn't bothered by this at all...

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard A designer where I work returned a QA release to dev because the gradient background hadn't been implemented according to the mockup. Some confusion ensued, until we realised the mockup did contain the gradient, but it was invisible on a low-end monitor.

Comment: I cleaned my screen and also clean my spec. Its difficult to see this network graph. I was thinking of going to the doctor.

Comment: I saw the pattern as it was intended, until I moved the window to my second monitor (which is usually the one that gives me *better* color accuracy) and yes it does look just like dirt, because the lines become nigh invisible.

Comment: Mmm, dirty pictures of graphs. Makes me want to go Dijkstra and Prim all over that graph.

Comment: Glad to see this. I suppose I can stop rubbing my screen off now.

Comment: I never even noticed it until I just read this. It looks looks like a connected global network type image.

Comment: Network graph?! I've been under the impression that it was a slab of concrete or something since SO is ROCK SOLID!

Comment: @gitsitgo Yes, from the hundreds of thousands of uniques over the past week you are the only one it doesn't bother.

Comment: Soooo glad that I'm not the only person that had this reaction.

Comment: Ha! I brushed my hand across it to wipe it off the first time I saw it too.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard Or, the designer just has a really dirty display.

Comment: 300th vote! Only noticed this now that it was mentioned. Am no designer but I think it's just trendy at the moment to use things like this within this kind of context. It kind of represent a network or web i guess which is cool, that being said i'm sure that better options do exist  - wheres the official contest? :)

Comment: I dunno, it didnt look dirty to me, i noticed right away it looked like a network. Maybe its my fancy monitors but it looked fine to me. May have to dig out an old tube monitor to compare ;-)

Comment: I am surprised that with this many upvotes, an admin has not changed the banner.

Comment: Is it bad that I thought it was a web connecting all the users who contributed to the success?

Comment: @warspyking It is bad and you should feel bad.

Comment: @cubuspl42 I'm ashamed, truly.

Comment: Am I the only one who rather scrolls with the mouse wheel in order to see whether something is indeed dirt on the screen, instead of raising the hand (ugh...) and wiping around, unnecessarily leaving fingerprints and smears...? Also: Every time you upvote this question, one designer gets fired :-(

Comment: If that was true the banner would have been updated by now ;)

Comment: @Marco13, as long as the designer getting fired is the one that made the dirty background banner strip, I don't mind :-)

Comment: Wow you only thought it was dirty? I thought my screen was cracked.

Comment: This has been bugging me for weeks - finally came to meta to see if anyone had posted about it. Then, was inspired to actually clean my screen. While cleaning the screen, I was thinking about this question, and *still*, despite all of that, I tried to clean a spot a couple of times before realizing it was the banner *again*.

Comment: At this point I just wish the banner would *go away*.

Comment: Haha, just found this. I'd definitely never done anything this popular before on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 159):

If you can't stand it so much that you're constantly trying to clean the screen, have goosebumps, shake uncontrollably, sweat and show signs of nervous tics, I have a solution (as long as you use Firefox or Google Chrome). It consists of 8 simple steps:

1. Install stylish

   1.1 If you use Firefox, go  [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)

   1.2 If you use Google Chrome, go [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en)

   1.3 If you use neither - you're doomed!
2. Find the [image: stylish] icon on your browser.

[image]

*Hint: It's in the upper right corner in Chrome and newer versions of Firefox and in the lower left corner of older Firefox versions*

3. Left-click on the icon, breathe in slowly, and left-click the last menu option:
   [image: write style for]
4. Add this to the text editor:

   ```
      #system-message {
        background: none;
      }
   ```
5. Name the style GOAWAYGOAWAYGOAWAY.
6. Save it.
7. Look at the screen! It's gone! Thank god, it's gone.
8. Go to a psychiatrist and have yourself examined. If prescribed with medication, drink it responsibly.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to do this, but +1 because this made me legitimately lol.

Comment: You couldn't work in UX industry, man.

Comment: ...or just wait until it's gone.

Comment: I feel obligated to explain why I don't accept this answer: I didn't really want the message to goawaygoaway (and if I did, I would manage to adblock it myself), just wanted to discuss the potential UX issue. No psychiatrist intervention is needed, neither is flame.

Comment: I feel obliged to express that I'm attempting to use my sense of humor on this website without trying to offend you, the topic or anybody/anything else.

Comment: I prefer `background-image: none`, which preserves `background-color`.

Comment: You're a rebel.

Comment: +1 for ignoring IE (and Edge or whatever that rebranded IE is).

Comment: Two options that work better: https://userstyles.org/styles/browse/stackoverflow

Comment: any help for IE6?

Comment: I'll assume that was a pun ^^

Comment: Do you thing this also works if I'm just feeling a bit dizzy over it?

Comment: Is there a plugin like this that does the same thing with HTML?

Comment: Naturally, ignore system messages at your own risk. :) Right now it's a celebratory type thing, but at other times it may be a downtime announcement, etc. That's rare, but could happen. (Or at the very least make a mental note to remove the style override once the logo changes back.)

Comment: They aren't ignored. They just don't have that dirty background image anymore.

Comment: They're just minimalistic!

Comment: @demonkoryu You know, it probably would help if I hadn't misread "background" as "display". Probably.

Comment: So the question says that "hey guys you did a sloppy job" and the top answer is "fix it yourself"?

Answer (score 36):

To  me it looks like an undirected graph, [kind of like the one you'd create in D3.js](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) or even [Processing](https://processing.org/), was used as part of the background.  It doesn't have any significance since even [the 10M page](https://stackoverflow.com/10m) makes use of the graph as a background in parts, but not in any significant data points.

Here's what it looks like with a dark background.

[image]

Comment: On my screen the lines are hardly visible on the left and nearly invisible on the right.

Comment: I can get you a rendering of the image making those lines clearer then if you'd like.

Comment: No, I can see them if I look close enough. I just think that it's an UX issue that needs to be discussed, actually there was one high-voted comment about this just under [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302940/1483676).

Comment: I thought it was confetti...

Comment: It's much clearer when you visit the link...

Comment: How is that an answer to "Is it only my personal feeling, or does that banner need a cleanup?" ?

Comment: I guess that the author meant "It looks _clearly_ like an undirected graph (so I think it's only your personal feeling)", just didn't say that directly. ;)

Comment: I can hardly see the lines with the dark background, but on the original it looks like two seperate graphs of interconnected nodes with the one on the left a kind of global shape

Comment: @CaptJak I guess you are still trying to write that love song, aren't you?

Comment: @TobiaTesan, please excuse me, I never meant to break your heart.

Answer (score 22):

An alternative to Hristo's solution:

1. In the rare event that you have not already done so: Install AdBlock Plus
2. Right-click on the background of the banner
3. In the context menu, select "AdBlock Plus: Block graphic..." (or similar)
4. In the following dialog, select the most specific filter (you don't want to accidentally block all SO graphics, do you?)
5. Click OK. You may have to reload the page to see the effect.

Comment: I know that this comment may case a flamewar but I think that you shouldn't use AdBlock on nice sites that you really like AND that don't show really bad ads (Flash, pop-up etc.) I have my AdBlock disabled for SO.

Comment: @Greg: I cannot see a problem in blocking just one SO image.

Comment: Folks using ad block are effectively stealing services.  If you don't like the ads on a site, don't use it.  There are plenty alternatives to everything on the internet.

Comment: Sure, @PJTraill, blocking single image is not a problem, but: a) if you don't have AdBlock installed yet then following all the steps in this answer will cause blocking all the ads on SO as most adblockers install ad filters by default, b) if you already have AdBlock then IF you are nice and allow ads from SO (have a whitelist) then will this single rule you add by following these steps have higher priority that the whitelist?

Comment: @Brad Comments are not for *fueling* a potential flame war. I disable ad-blocking on sites that I am not paying money for and that don't have *intrusive* ads (like auto-playing audio/video), e.g. StackExchange. It's the job of advertisement coordinators to ensure that the ads they use don't interfere with user experience, thus the several posts on Meta about ads and the SE team's very quick responses in dealing with intrusive advertising.

Comment: @GregDubicki The whitelist is unaffected by targeted blocks. I have StackOverflow whitelisted, then right-clicked the banner (#system-message) and selectively blocked it. The whitelisting allows ads to load while still blocking the banner. So yes, targeted blocks have higher priority than the whitelist. That also means that if SE ever has an  intrusive ad, you can selectively block it while allowing all of the others through.

Comment: Ok, since the comments on this answer are wandering off topic anyway, let's talk about __Unicorns!__

Comment: Eh, pointy horses with delusions of grandeur.

Comment: Which part of a unicorn do you find most tasty?

Comment: Man, you saved my life. This banner was giving me goosebumps and made me shake uncontrollably.

Comment: I FEED MY UNICORNS UNICORN MEAT

Comment: @RobertPounder That's evil!