# At what point do we stop the "We've reached 10 million questions" celebration?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

(This is not a duplicate of [Stack Overflow title edit to 'celebrate' 10 million questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302923/stack-overflow-title-edit-to-celebrate-10-million-questions), because I'm not asking about why there are so many *o*s in the site name.)

While 10,000,000 questions is quite an impressive milestone, and might have been worthy of a celebratory break from the norm here, at what point do we stop and go back to this being a somewhat focused site?

I enjoy a good party as much as anyone else, but even a great New Year's Eve celebration has to end at some point, and it seems to me there's been enough of a party for this event when it gains it's own tag to collect the cruft into a topic.

When do we stop generating all of the extra clutter so that we can focus on the purpose of this site again? It's hard to find actual questions and discussion here because you can't sift through all of the nonsense. Even the hats stop sometime; can't the milestone as well? We have to be at more than 10,000,100 questions now. Can we start shooting for the milestone of 20M?

Comment: @CRABOLO I didn't ask why the title was changed to *Stackoverflooooooow`. I asked **when will the entire celebration stop?*. They're two totally different things, and if you can't tell the difference you need to read them both again carefully. :-)

Comment: The first and only  question I see there is "I'm guessing it will just stick around for the day?" Then the accepted answer answers that question saying we'll be celebrating for about a month says that's how long the contests to win swag are, and does say they might remove the title sooner than the month though but keep the 10m page up.

Comment: SELECT * FROM META WHERE NONSENSE = 0;

Comment: @CRABOLO: And again, that's **not my question**. My question is *When do we stop the site logo change, the banner on the main site pages, and all of the noise and clutter here in Meta?*, which is **not the same question**. I could care less about how many *o*s they choose to put in the site logo. I'm tired of sifting through all of the noise in the questions here on Meta about the celebration to find questions that actually are related to **the operation  and function of SO itself**.

Comment: The questioner's original question in revision list is definitely not a dup but it was edited to something different. I think the current rev is a dup. The answer you'll receive here will probably be close to the same as in the other one (a month). Since they already did a Week 1 winners , you can probably except a Week 4 winners thread in the future. You can ignore the 10m-questions-milestone tag to either grey out or hide questions about it.

Comment: @Ken Does this mean there will be a celebration once the celebration ends?  Are we invited?

Comment: @CRABOLO: You're getting confused. You're thinking *Well, there's another question that has the 'c' tag, and it also has the word 'main' in it, so they must be duplicates.*. I'm trying to explain that, even though you might think they are, they aren't. **I'm specifically asking about all of the extra posts here in Meta that hide other actual relevant questions or information** - I don't give a flip about the extra ooooooooo in the main site's logo (although the space wasted by the *come share with us (Kumbaya)* space is a little irritating).

Comment: @CRABOLO: And let he who has less than 2000 answers on the 'Flow be the first one to point out the irrelevant. Do you want to get into K's of repo on the 'Flow next? Why are you trying to make this personal?

Comment: @PetahChristian: Sure. You're invited to my next birthday party. :-) I'll warn you ahead of time, though; it doesn't last for days, and we try to limit the mess to what will fit in a single Dumpster.

Comment: What is the celebration you're talking about? The only thing that's different I've noticed is the logo and the contest threads... What else is not being a "somewhat focused site" ?

Comment: @Rob: Well, let's start with the tag I mentioned (10m-questions-milestone), which didn't exist before. Look at the questions with that tag.  Look at the first few pages of Meta - how many questions are related to the milestone? Look at the question that keeps popping up at the top of the Meta page (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey), over and over and over again, pushing actual questions off the page. Add the dozens of questions about the milestone that aren't tagged that do the same.

Comment: @KenWhite On the first page of meta, there's 43 questions. 5 of them are tagged with `10m-questions-milestone`. One of them is a bug - not discussion about the milestone. One of them is this question. Two of them are contests. The final one is fluff, I agree. So we've got 2 questions sticking to the top - the contents, and one fluff question. That doesn't really seem to bad to me. And it's clear the contest threads will die when the contests finish... so there's your answer, I guess? Meta is hardly active enough that 2 question threads are hiding real questions, anyway.

Comment: @Rob: That's at this particular instant. I'm not referring to only those two questions, and not referring only to those that have the tag in question. I've been wading through the **50** questions I see on the first page of Meta for several days trying to pick out the questions. The fact you see a snapshot where they don't *really seem so bad* is great. Once in a while, I also catch a snap view of the main pages that aren't cluttered with a dozen  *[on hold]* questions, too. :-) And for a miracle second, you may catch a glimpse of a page in the PHP tag that doesn't have all negative votes.

Comment: @Rob: An [example of one not tagged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305271/62576) (and of course the one it duplicates) currently in the top 10.

Comment: @Rob: And [another one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305269/62576). Tell me when I should stop.

Comment: Celebrations? All I see is some text about it, and a silly logo.  It's something to celebrate, certainly, but when and where do the celebrations start? It's like a party I'm not invited to!  Perhaps the term "sombre reflection" would be more accurate?

Comment: I gather from your comments that your question is directed not at SE but at  other Meta users: i.e. "When are you clowns^W^Wwe, my dear fellow SOers, going to stop talking about this?" If I understand that correctly, then I agree it's not a duplicate, but it also seems to lack resolvability. Are you trying to get some kind of consensus that we should ignore the milestone?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: The consensus was what I was hoping to get, which in turn I hoped would get the attention of SE. I never indicated at any point that we should *ignore the milestone*, though. My friends (and i) celebrate birthdays every year, because it's a milestone (yet another year of being alive), but I'd bet they'd be pretty annoyed if every year I made noise for two weeks leading up to my birthday, celebrated loudly on the day, and then continued to go on about it for the next month. I guess the consensus wasn't here (although I'm a little bothered by the close voters that didn't read.

Comment: Well, I've voted to reopen, but it doesn't look like anyone else agrees.

Comment: @Josh: Thanks. I appreciate the effort. :-)

Comment: the embarrassing banner in question has *finally* been removed, so this is moot thank goodness.  if you're reading this in the far future and wonder what it was all about .. err, just move along  :O

Comment: @JoeBlow: It appears to be back today, so not moot (yet).

Answer (score 5):

I imagine things will get back to "normal" once the contests have ended.

Since it sounds like the celebration will be going on for a month, you may have to ignore the tag(s) you don't want to see, until that "noise and clutter" die down.

**Update:**

You can add `10m-questions-milestone` to your ignored tags, and select **Hide questions in your ignored tags** so the questions won't be visible.

Comment: Sure. I can add `feature-request` to my ignored tags, so that I don't see [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305271/62576) as well. I can also just not visit Meta for a month or two, until the distractions disappear. I can also just avoid SO several times a year until all of the college homework questions are finished.*I know! I'll just hide my head in the sand until the problem goes away*, said the ostrich.

Comment: Is it *really* such a big deal?